# How to generate the file names as follows?

Tags: export

Suppose I have two variables called `var1` and `var2` which can have arbitrary values. I use them in a toy example as follows

```
val1 = 0.001;
val2 = 500;
f[x_] := val1 + 10 x/val2;
p1 = Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotLegends -> "plot 1"];
Export["name.PNG", p1]
```

Since I have to change the values of `val1` and `val2` each time, I intend to write an appropriate code for naming the exported file name so that it is not necessary to name it manually. For example I want to use a combination of a constant string ("plot_function" for example),`val1` and `val2` for naming the file as follows:

file name="plot_function"_val1_val2

In fact I look for a general way to generate a string composed from different identities (in this case variables and strings) which can be used as argument of Print[] or naming an file and etc.
I tried `ToExpression[val1]` but I have no idea how to proceed?!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use a [`StringTemplate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringTemplate.html) for this,

```
In[46]:= StringTemplate["name_`1`_`2`.PNG"][val1, val2]

Out[46]= "name_0.001_500.PNG"
```

Comment: I would avoid the extra `"."` in filenames. Probably translating it to `""name_0p001_500.PNG""` ?

Comment: @JasonB OMG! what a simple and lovely code! Thanks!

Comment: `StringTemplate` is nice! I usually use a mess of `StringJoin` for this. Thanks!